# How do I get a counter that shows only a single number?

Tags: numbering, theorems, counters

I am using article, in case that matters. By default, a theorem is numbered in this format:

**Theorem 1.2**

But I would like to change it to

**Theorem 2**

i.e. without the "x." part but just a single number starting from 1. How should I do it?

Comment: The default for theorems in `article` is to be numbered with a single digit. That is, *not* with an **x.y** format. Can you please provide a minimal example that starts with `\documentclass` and ends with `\end{document}` that replicates your current behaviour? That would be much appreciated...

Comment: There are several possible reasons for the subordinated numbering of `theorem` environments. For instance, how is the `theorem` environment defined? Possibly as `\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[section]`? Or does the preamble of your document per chance contain either `\numberwithin{theorem}{section}` or `\counterwithin{theorem}{section}`? Without further information (other than the fact that you use the `article` document class), it's not really possible to offer a serious diagnosis.

Comment: @Mico Yeah I used a \newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[counter] command at the beginning. But I don't know which counter to use for what I want. (I am currently using section)

Comment: Does your code contain `\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[counter]` or `\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[section]`? Please clarify. By the way, if you do *not* want to subordinate the `theorem` counter to any other counter (say, the counter called `section`), just write `\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}`.

Comment: @Mico Thanks, this works. I didn't know one could do that. But how do I access this counter if I don't put anything in the square brackets, in case I need to modify its value?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You mentioned in a comment that

> I used a `\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[section]` command [in the preamble]. But I don't know which counter to use for what I want.

Some comments and observations:

- If you run `\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}` in the preamble, then `theorem` is both the name of the environment *and* the name of the counter associated with that environment. Moreover, the counter called `theorem` is not subordinated to any other counter.

  Judging by your query, I believe that this is what you want.
- In contrast, if you run `\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[section]`, `theorem` is still both the name of the environment and the counter associated with that environment. But now the `theorem` counter is *subordinated* to the `section` counter. And, assuming the value of the `section` counter is, say, 3, the `theorem` counter will be displayed as 3.1, 3.2, etc -- unless you modified the macro `\thetheorem`.
- You also asked, "But how do I access the [`theorem`] counter ... in case I need to modify its value?"

  Assuming the `theorem` counter is not subordinated, you would "access" the counter just like you would access any other counter. E.g., you could use either `\thetheorem` or `\arabic{theorem}` to display its value, and you could use `\setcounter`, `\addtocounter`, `\stepcounter`, or `\refstepcounter` to change its value. (The latter two commands increment the value of the counter by exactly `1`.)

Comment: Thanks again! This is a very clear explanation of how counters work.